# Tools to easily generate Typescript Declaration Files

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I wrote a Javascript library in Typescript and I'd like to include a Declaration file with the distribution package. Are there any tools that I can use in Visual Studio 2015 to easily to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frank Bessou pointed me in the right direction, but there is no actual need for a tsconfig.json file. It's much simpler to just right-click on the project => Properties => TypeScrypt Build and there we can find the option "Generate declaration files".

Answer (score 5):

You can set the `declaration` property to true in your tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "declaration": true
    },
    ...
}
```